# What is the difference between "cigarrillo", "cigarro" and "puro"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, sinónimos

I have translated "cigar" into Spanish. There are three translations for that.

> **cigarrillo**
>
> **cigarro**
>
> **puro**

Hypothesis: Spanish people told me that *cigarillo* and *cigarro* are the same. And that *puro* is a different product.

What is a difference between them?

Comment: yeah, Spanish people told me that cigarillo and cigarro are the same. And that puro is a different product. In Argetina they also call it "pucho m".

Comment: *Cigarillo* means cigarette rather than cigar.

Comment: I have found online that cigarillo means a thin cigar: http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=Cigarillo

Comment: Actually in Spain both mean the very same: cigarro, cigarrillo, pitillo, piti...

Comment: Cigarro is a "cigarette" = cigarrillo es un diminutivo. Puro es un tabacco. Tabacco en ingles les llaman cigar

Comment: @Wandy In a lot of Central America "tabaco" or "cigarro" means cigarette, but "cigaro" (no double r) means cigar

Answer (score 6):

[Cigarro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9CBLSi4)

> 1. m. Rollo de hojas de tabaco, que se enciende por un extremo y se chupa o fuma por el opuesto.

[Puro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UisSmCT)

> 9. m. Cigarro hecho de hojas de tabaco enrolladas y liado sin papel.

So the translation of "**cigar**" would be cigarro = puro = cigarro puro (less used), whilst

[Cigarrillo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9C7p3Gg)

> Cigarro pequeño de picadura envuelta en un papel de fumar.

would be "cigarette".

Though these are the formal definitions.  Informally, people often use "cigarro" for "cigarrillo", as "cigarrillo" can sound corny.

Comment: Just as a comment, another word for *cigarette* widely used in Spain is *pitillo*.

Comment: @Yay spain and south america.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to be less academic because I think that this question is worth to be answered with images:

In Spain (actually):

Puro:

[image: Puro]

Cigarro - Cigarrillo:

[image: Cigarrillo - Cigarro]

Comment: I heard `cigarro` and `cigarro puro` for the former, and `cigarro` and `cigarrillo`  for the latter.