# "Pack of cigarettes" and "carton of cigarettes" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

I am translating "pack of cigarettes" and "carton of cigarettes" into Spanish.

- pack of cigarettes

> [image]

- carton of cigarettes

> [image]

Here is what I already have:

- pack of cigarettes:

  - cajetilla de cigarrillos
  - cajita de cigarrillos
- carton of cigarettes

  - cartón de tabaco
  - caja de cigarrillos
  - paquete de cigarrillos
  - paquete de tabaco

Is that correct?

If there are more ways how to express one thing, what is the difference between them? Do some expressions means just the paper box and some other the paper box with prefferebly full amount of cigarettes?

Comment: By the way, I have never heard someone in English refer to a carton of cigarettes, that just sounds strange to me.

Comment: As a native English speaker, I’d understand a ‘carton of cigarettes’ to refer to a multi-pack.

Answer (score 4):

The following applies at least in Spain, Colombia and Argentina (according to the comments). For a pack of cigarettes we say:

- Un [paquete de tabaco](https://www.google.es/search?hl=es&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1175&bih=904&q=paquete%20de%20tabaco).
- Un [paquete de cigarrillos](https://www.google.es/search?hl=es&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1175&bih=904&q=paquete%20de%20cigarrillos).
- Un paquete de [brand].

For a carton of cigarettes we say:

- Un [cartón de tabaco](https://www.google.es/search?hl=es&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1175&bih=904&q=carton%20de%20tabaco).
- Un [cartón de cigarrillos](https://www.google.es/search?hl=es&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=934&q=cart%C3%B3n%20de%20cigarrillos).
- Un cartón de [brand].

For no specific reason, "un cartón de cigarrillos" does not sound natural to me. I suppose it is because "cartón" implies a big amount and "cigarrillos" is a diminutive, and it is kind of a contradiction to have those two words together. But it is confirmed to be used.

All of this expressions represent both the box/boxes and the content (the cigarettes).

Following with the comments, some countries use *cajetilla* rather than *paquete* (Mexico, Chile), and Argentina seems to have some other options of their own: *atado* (pack) and *box* (cardboard packs).

For the differences between *cigarrillos* and *cigarros*, see [this other question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18397/what-is-the-difference-between-cigarrillo-cigarro-and-puro).

Comment: All of this examples are used exactly the same in Colombia and we do use "un cartón de cigarrillos" also....but you better quit smoking :-)

Comment: @DGaleano just for the record, I don't smoke, so I agree with you, everybody please quit smoking! :-)

Comment: In Argentina, a carton of cigarettes is called a _cartón de cigarrillos_. A pack of cigarettes is properly called an _atado de cigarrillos_, although _paquete_ is becoming more common nowadays. If the pack is made of cardboard instead of paper, it is calles a _box_, as in English.

Comment: In Mexico a pack would be - Una cajetilla de cigarros

Comment: Chile: cajetilla y cartón. Cigarros and cigarrillos are used more or less indistinctly (maybe _cigarros_ is more informal).

Answer (score 1):

When I ask for a *paquete* in Guanajuato (Mexico) they head for the storeroom to get a carton. Apparently a pack here is *cajetillo*

Answer (score 0):

This applies to Mexico:

When buying it is always assumed you want a pack of cigarettes.

```
- Good morning, how can I help you?
- A pack of cigarettes, please.
```

Translates to:

```
- Buenos días, ¿qué se le ofrece?
- Unos cigarros.
```

Literal translation will be "un paquete de cigarros" (where `paquete` is spanish for `pack`) and that means around 20 packs of cigarettes.

En cambio:

```
- ¿Cuánto has estado fumando?
- Una caja* diario. (one pack a day).
```

*caja, cajetilla.